# Add image URL without loading image that passes Google Structured Data tester

Tags: html, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

I am trying to enable Google's Rich Snippets for articles, and it keeps demanding an image for the article. I don't actually want to display an image on the page so how do I mark it up so that it provides Google with the URL for the image? Using something like -

```
    <div class='container' id="content-text" typeof="Article">

        <span typeof="imageObject">
            <span property="image"><span property="contentUrl" content="/static/imgs/protraits/{{content.author|san_str}}.jpg"></span></span>
        </span>

        <h1><span property="name">{{ content.title }}</span></h1>
        <h2>{% if content.subtitle %}{{ content.subtitle }}{% endif %}
        <small>by <span property="author">{{ content.author }}</span></small></h2>

    <div property="articleBody">{{ content.text|safe }}</div>
    </div>
```

I was able to get the tester to recognize an image object but it is separate from the article object. If I try to make the image a property of the article it tells me that `contentUrl` is not a valid property of `Article`.

Comment: Note that URIs are case-sensitive, so it must be `ImageObject` instead of `imageObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `link` element:

```
<div typeof="Article">
  <link property="image" href="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Or with specifying the type explicitly:

```
<div typeof="Article">
  <link property="image" typeof="ImageObject" href="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

For Google’s [Article Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles), you seem to have to provide the `height` and `width` properties for the image (they are listed as *required*), so it could look like:

```
<div typeof="Article">
  <div property="image" typeof="ImageObject">
    <link property="url" href="image.jpg" />
    <meta property="height" content="50" />
    <meta property="width" content="50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as that.  Though just a note, I did have to provide the type or it give the error: The attribute itemtype has an invalid value.

Comment: @Walt.B: Ah, yeah, thanks -- for Google’s Article Rich Snippet, the `height` and `width` properties seem to be required (and then you’d have to provide the image’s URL in the `url` property), although their testing tool doesn’t (always?) seem to note this. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah I actually noticed that after the fact. Still it pointed me in the right direction, thanks again.